# Error using simple decorator in Python

Tags: python

```
def simple_decorator(f):
    def tmp(*args, **kwargs):
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return res
    return tmp

@simple_decorator
class FirstClass():
    pass


@simple_decorator
class SecondClass(FirstClass):
    pass
```

I have error:

```
File "1.py", line 16, in <module>
class SecondClass(FirstClass):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Why ?

Answer (score 6):

Your decorator returns a *function*, so `FirstClass` is a function, not a class; decorators are not required to return an object that is the same type as the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you're trying to decorate a class.
Check [PEP-3129](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/).

Comment: Class decorators were introduced in Py3k, and backported to 2.6.